# Update with id from url

Tags: pdo

Currently I'm trying to run an update from a url ID, I can retrieve it ID however something seems wrong with my update, not really sure where I'm going wrong

```
 require_once'connection.php';



        $getCode = $db->prepare("
                        SELECT username, activecode FROM username WHERE activecode = ?
                    ");
        $getCode->execute( array ( $_GET["activecode"] ) );


$sql = "UPDATE `username` SET `active` = '1'
    WHERE `activecode` = :activecode"; 

//  var_dump($sql);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':activecode', $getCode);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
   require_once'connection.php';
   $getCode = $db->prepare(" SELECT username, activecode FROM username WHERE activecode = :activecode");
   $getCode->bindParam(':activecode', $_GET["activecode"] );
   $getCode->execute( );


   $sql = "UPDATE username SET active = '1'  WHERE activecode = :activecode"; 
 //  var_dump($sql);
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(':activecode',  $_GET["activecode"]);
 $stmt->execute();
?>
```